# What is meant by ideal transformers transform resistances as well?

Tags: transformer

If V₁ is the amplitude voltage of the primary, I₁ is its amplitude current, V₂ is the amplitude of the secondary, and R₂ is a load resistance, then the following is true $$V_{1}/I_{1}=R_{2}/(N_{2}/N_{1})^{2}$$

Does that mean if have a machine which is designed to operate from a line with V₂, I can make it operate directly from the line with V₁ if i was capable of transforming its resistance according to the above equation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by 'the resistance', in the context of a 'machine'.

If you had two machines of the same size and power, one designed to work from V1, the other designed to work from V2, you find the resistances of the windings would be in that ratio.

You would find their 'impedances', the ratio of V to I at the terminals of each machine would be in that ratio.

If you had an ideal transformer with turns ratio N, then a resistance across its secondary would 'look like' a resistance of N<sup>2</sup>R (or R/N<sup>2</sup>) at the primary.